# Why is $|\bar{K}^0\rangle=\mathscr{CP}|K^0\rangle$ and not $|\bar{K}^0\rangle=\mathscr{C}|K^0\rangle$?

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, parity, cp-violation, charge-conjugation

If the charge conjugation operator $\mathscr{C}$ changes a particle state into the corresponding anti-particle state then we must write $|\bar{K}^0\rangle=\mathscr{C}|K^0\rangle$. But instead, we write $|\bar{K}^0\rangle=\mathscr{CP}|K^0\rangle$ where $\mathscr{P}$ is the parity operator. $|K^0\rangle$ and $|\bar{K}^0\rangle$ stands for the neutral Kaon states. Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 3):

All these states, and so their linear combinations, are pseudoscalars, so, then, odd under *P*, and thus essentially *P= –1* throughout.

This is a feature of [Dirac equation solution bilinears](http://www.physics.indiana.edu/~dermisek/QFT_09/qft-I-12-2p.pdf). Pure *C* does give you a state of opposite strangeness, but not quite what you will use later on, when you will contrast weak decays of the standard linear combinations, where *P* and *C* are violated maximally, but *CP* is (mostly) preserved.  Parity flips the chirality of the constituent quarks, but *C* does not.

Consider the states in question, $\bar{K}^0\sim \bar{d} i\gamma_5 s$ versus  $K^0\sim \bar{s}i\gamma_5 d$. The operation that *completely* transforms them to each other with the role of *s* completely supplanted by that of *d* is *CP*. In a world with only 2 generations, weak charged currents would couple to these quarks identically (In that world, the weak interactions would preserve CP, all the while breaking *C* and *P* identically. Only the strong interactions preserve *C* and *P* separately.), as the left-handed *s* supplanted the left-handed *d*, instead of the right-handed one, had one skipped operation by *P*.

(Consider that *only* *CP* maps left-handed neutrinos to EW-flavored right-handed antineutrinos; *C* or *P* map to the sterile states, which is why the weak interactions violate them--maximally.)

You would have an analogous situation for the charged *K* brethren of these states, but, being of opposite charge, they would not interfere, as electromagnetic interactions would treat them very differently. So, for them, you never find yourself in a situation where the *CP* operation is needed instead of just plain *C*, I think (or do you?).

- A small nitpick on the question's unwarranted assertion that 
  $|\bar{K}^0\rangle=C|K^0\rangle$. Not quite! All you need is $C^2 |K^0\rangle= |K^0\rangle$, so $-|\bar{K}^0\rangle=C|K^0\rangle $ would *also* do, provided $C|\bar{K}^0\rangle=-|K^0\rangle$. This amounts to $C(|K^0\rangle+|\bar{K}^0\rangle)=-(|K^0\rangle+|\bar{K}^0\rangle)$, so then *CP*-even, and the orthogonal combination *C*-even but *CP*-odd. So, then, the effective term of the common weak decay $K_s\to \pi^0 \pi^0$ in the effective action is $K_S \pi^0\pi^0$. Since everybody has *P= -1*, and *C* for the neutral πs is +, the term violates *P* and *C*, but preserves *CP*, like a good weak effective vertex.